# Give each cell an unique tag (incremental number)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Is there a way to give each cell in a grouped tableview an incremental number as its tag?

E.g:

Group 1

- cell 1 (tag = 1)
- cell 2 (tag = 2)
- cell 3 (tag = 3)

Group 2

- cell 1 (tag = 4)
- cell 2 (tag = 5)

Group 3

- cell 1 (tag = 6)

etc...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible without querying the datasource for the count of cells that are in previous groups. And you probably don't want to do that. Doesn't make sense anyway, because you have to implement proper reuse to get good performance, so tags appear and disappear any time.

So the real question is, why do you want to do this? There is probably a way to achieve the same without adding tags.

But if you really want to:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSInteger count = 1;
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < indexPath.section; i++) {
        count += [[tableView dataSource] tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
    }
    count += indexPath.row;
    // dequeue, create and configure...
    cell.tag = count;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Well basically I've set-up my app in a way that I need to know if the 4th, 5th, 6th etc.. cell is pressed. I used a non grouped tableview, which allowed me to use the `indexpath.row`, but now I have to switch to a grouped style tableview, which messes up this system.

Comment: so maybe you should try to rearrange your data source. A NSArray (for the rows) in a NSArray (for the sections) or something like that. But maybe the code from the answer will already fit your needs.

Comment: Although this was the wrong approach to my problem; you answer is correct. So I'll accept. The right approach was indeed in the rearranging of the data source

Answer (score -2):

1. Create a variable
2. Create a loop which will iterate through all cells
3. At the end of each loop add 1 to the variable

Comment: That might work if you create all the cells in advance, but the usual practice is to recycle cells so that you only need about as many cells as it takes to fill the screen.

Comment: I see... Sorry if this didn't helped